# Align vertical object over horizontal order?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I have more than 100 object that is alligned to the right edge with fixed space (VERTICALLY)
I need to put them (HORIZONTALLY) with the same fixed space and perfect align to its bottom!

### Like the attached image

### [image]

I have tried many times .... what I did is to collect all objects to the center of the first one >>>>> then I RE-DISTRIBUTED Horizontally ...
((((((( BUT ))))))) the problem is that they aren't distributed in the same order ... asume that we have numbers ... we may find this order :: 5 4 2 1 3
How can I fix that >> 
Thirsty to SOLVE it ... thanks for every help :)

Comment: What program are you using? What have you tried? What do you mean by "they aren't distributed in the same order"? This question is very unclear and I'm voting to close it as such

Comment: I sorry because my question wasn't clear enough ...!

Comment: I'm using Adobe Illustrator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your using Adobe Illustrator.

Take the whole group and rotate it 90 degrees. Then select Object-->Transform-->Transform Each to rotate each object back -90 degrees to put them straight again.

You might have to use the arrange/distribute to clean it up.